# Program printing the wrong variable from channel

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    c := make(chan int, 5)
    c <- 5
    c <- 6
    close(c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)

}
```

shouldn't the program above print 6 since it is the last value sent to the channel?

Whay is more, is it possible to print / receiving from a closed channel?

It prints 5

Comment: Channels are FIFO https://gobyexample.com/channel-buffering

Comment: clearly you need to read the doc and specification. https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Golang channels are FIFO, first in first out. That is why 5 gets printed out first.

EDIT: Closing channel indicates that no more data will be send to it.

> "If a channel is closed, you can still read data. But you cannot send
> new data into it. This program reads both before and after closing the
> channel, which works. It’s closed only for sending"

https://golangr.com/close-channel/